# Using Postman to get next iteration

Tags: curl, postman

I'm using Postman to get results from a web service.

The web service splits the results into chunks of 50, with the next request URL within the previous JSON return like this:

```
{
    "type": "user.list",
    "pages": {
        "type": "pages",
        "next": "https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page=50&page=2",
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 50,
        "total_pages": 2721
    },
...
```

Is there a way I can automatically request the next page until I have all the results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can parse the `next` in your response and set the value of next to `postman.setNextRequest('<next url>')`.

Eg - In your tests section add this code

```
try {
  var userList = JSON.parse(responseBody);

  // Do whatever you have to do with the response 
  // Check if userList.pages.next is valid string 
  // If valid do

  postman.setNextRequest(userList.pages.next);

} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error parsing JSON', e);
  postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Ref - [Conditional Workflows in Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/building_workflows)

Comment: Could you add some information on how this will work. I have tried this but Postman returns `setNextRequest is not defined` error even though I know there is a valid next page value.

Comment: It is `postman.setNextRequest`. You can check the linked reference for details.

Comment: Although this works (I can confirm by the load time being doubled), I can't see the additional results in the response. Also how can I chain this so that it will get all next pages and not just the second iteration.

Comment: Add `console.log` statements to your test script to log the `next` url that you parsed. The `setNextRequest` calls the same request recursively, so if it is only running twice, that means there are only two pages. You can open via `View->Show Postman Console` and also check the `View->Devtools`

Comment: I can't find `Show Postman Console` or `Devtools` options anywhere. The JSON return has more than 2700 pages, I know this because I have manually requested pages 1-5.

Comment: Use the native Postman app -  https://www.getpostman.com/apps

Also would help if you post your code you have written here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152529/discussion-between-imran-and-pratik-mandrekar).

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this is an old post, but I wanted to share an answer for other Postman users who might be struggling. This answer also includes methods for looping through an API that does NOT provide the "next URL" in the response.

First thing you can do is use a variable for the page number in your original API call. In the JSON response you provided, the "next" URL is as follows:

```
https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page=50&page=2
```

If you use this as your original URL, then you can simply replace the hard page number with a variable, like this:

```
https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page=50&page={{pageNumber}}
```

In order to make this run successfully on your first all, use the **Pre-Request Scripts** tab to define your initial pageNumber:

```
if (!pm.variables.get("pageNumber")) {
    pageNumber = 1;
    pm.variables.set("pageNumber", pageNumber);
}
```

NOTE: Make sure you define the correct scope for your variable. Here I used "pm.variables.set", which is local. You can also use "collection", "environment" or "global" variables, depending on your need.

Next, in the **Tests** tab, you can add a line of code to iterate to the next page and call the API again. You will need to add a condition to make sure you aren't iterating forever.

A good condition based on your needs is the page number. Since the responseBody shows the "total_pages", you can compare that against the current pageNumber.

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const totalPages = jsonData.pages.total_pages;
let pageNumber = pm.variables.get("pageNumber");

if (pageNumber < totalPages) {
    pageNumber++; //this increments the variable by 1;
    pm.variables.set("pageNumber", pageNumber);
    postman.setNextRequest("https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page={{perPageCount}}&page={{pageNumber}}");
}
```

Another thing you can try is increasing the "per page" count to increase the number of results for each API call. I've been able to increase the "per page" count from 50 to 1,000 (one thousand). This saves a lot of time making multiple calls, but you'll have to test and confirm the highest number you can successfully retrieve that gives you the data you want:

```
https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page={{perPageCount}}&page={{pageNumber}}
```

You don't need to iterate the {{perPageCount}} variable. You just need to define it once. If you know the maximum useful page count, you can simply hard code it in:

```
https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page=1000&page={{pageNumber}}
```

You can also use the **Pre-Request Script** to set a variable:

```
const perPageCount = 1000;
pm.variables.set("perPageCount", perPageCount);

https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page={{perPageCount}}&page={{pageNumber}}
```

### Bringing this all together

If I was building a Postman collection to loop this API call multiple times, This is how I would build it:

Pre-Request Script:

```
if (!pm.variables.get("pageNumber")) {
    pageNumber = 1;
    pm.variables.set("pageNumber", pageNumber);
}

const perPageCount = 1000;
pm.variables.set("perPageCount", perPageCount);
```

URL:

```
https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page={{perPageCount}}&page={{pageNumber}}
```

Tests:

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const totalPages = jsonData.pages.total_pages;
let pageNumber = pm.variables.get("pageNumber");

if (pageNumber < totalPages) {
    pageNumber++; //this increments the variable by 1;
    pm.variables.set("pageNumber", pageNumber);
    postman.setNextRequest("https://api.webservice.io/users?per_page={{perPageCount}}&page={{pageNumber}}");
}
```

Lastly, in order for this to work, you must run the Postman Collection Runner. You can't simply call the API individually. You can find the details on [how to use the Collection Runner](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/running-collections/intro-to-collection-runs/) in the Postman Docs.