# Using postman to get all pages in a paginated response

Tags: postman

```
{
"users": [...],
"next_page": "https://junk.example.com/api/v2/users.json?page=2",
"previous_page": null,
"count": 1091
}
```

The sample above is what I receive in the response body. I am trying to automate postman to pull each page automatically. I have seen documentation about conditional workflows in postman but I can't seem to get it to work. I have used a sample example from [this post made last year.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815359/using-postman-to-get-next-iteration?answertab=active#tab-top) But that example doesn't seem to be gelling well with my situation. See attempted test code below.

```
try {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  //var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

  //The above commented code is my attempt to alter the original example 
  //in the hopes of a solution.

  postman.setNextRequest(jsonData.next_page);

} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error parsing JSON', e);
  postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

As you may already can see  have tried to alter it to see if a different method of extracting the next_page object would solve the problem but so far no luck. I receive no error the get request simply doesn't run the next page when I try to do a collection run.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pm.sendRequest on the Pre-request Script or the Tests tab. The example below, I have put on the Tests tab. Use the 'Show Postman Console' to see the results:

```
# Recursive function that will call all of the pages
function callMyRequest(nextUrl) {
    pm.sendRequest({
        url: nextUrl,
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            # Basic tests about the response (res)
            pm.test("Response code is 200", function() {
                pm.expect(res).to.have.property('code', 200);
            });
                
            # Check for the next page
            if (res.json().next_page !== null) {
                callMyRequest(res.json().next_page);
            } else {
                # Stop iterations
                postman.setNextRequest(null);
            }
        }
    });
}

# Basic tests about the main response (pm.response)
pm.test("Response code is 200", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response).to.have.property('code', 200);
});

# We need to check if there is pagination   
if (pm.response.json().next_page !== null) {
    callMyRequest(pm.response.json().next_page);
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that postman.setNextRequest() works slightly different: during the collection runner execution, it sets next request basing on the name of request in the collection. In your case instead of providing the name of next request in your collection, you're providing the actual URL you want to follow.

The easiest way to send such request is to add new request in your collection, which can be named `'NextRequest'`, and provide an environmental variable `{{nextRequestUrl}}` as URL.

In your first request, you can perform the following code to add actual URL of next page to the environmental variable

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

if(jsonData.next_page != null){
    pm.environment.set('nextRequestUrl', jsonData.next_page)
    postman.setNextRequest('NextRequest');
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

And in your `'NextRequest'` request, you can add the same script on the Test tab.